# Error by setting up firebase configurations

Tags: javascript, node.js, angular, typescript, firebase-realtime-database

I configure my firebase and i have a lot of errors. I dont know why that apears.

```
Error: node_modules/@angular/fire/compat/analytics/analytics.d.ts:22:21 - error TS2694: Namespace '"/home/miguel/PhpstormProjects/pictureDragAndDrop/node_modules/@angular/core/core"' has no exported member 'ɵɵFactoryDeclaration'.
```

22     static ɵfac: i0.ɵɵFactoryDeclaration<AngularFireAnalytics, [null, { optional: true; }, { optional: true; }, { optional: true; }, { optional: true; }, { optional: true; }, null, null, null]>;
~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

Error: node_modules/@angular/fire/compat/analytics/analytics.d.ts:23:22 - error TS2694: Namespace '"/home/miguel/PhpstormProjects/pictureDragAndDrop/node_modules/@angular/core/core"' has no exported member 'ɵɵInjectableDeclaration'.

23     static ɵprov: i0.ɵɵInjectableDeclaration;
~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

Error: node_modules/@angular/fire/compat/analytics/analytics.module.d.ts:7:21 - error TS2694: Namespace '"/home/miguel/PhpstormProjects/pictureDragAndDrop/node_modules/@angular/core/core"' has no exported member 'ɵɵFactoryDeclaration'.

7     static ɵfac: i0.ɵɵFactoryDeclaration<AngularFireAnalyticsModule, [null, { optional: true; }, { optional: true; }]>;
~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

Error: node_modules/@angular/fire/compat/analytics/analytics.module.d.ts:8:21 - error TS2694: Namespace '"/home/miguel/PhpstormProjects/pictureDragAndDrop/node_modules/@angular/core/core"' has no exported member 'ɵɵNgModuleDeclaration'.

8     static ɵmod: i0.ɵɵNgModuleDeclaration<AngularFireAnalyticsModule, never, never, never>;
~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

Error: node_modules/@angular/fire/compat/analytics/analytics.module.d.ts:9:21 - error TS2694: Namespace '"/home/miguel/PhpstormProjects/pictureDragAndDrop/node_modules/@angular/core/core"' has no exported member 'ɵɵInjectorDeclaration'.

9     static ɵinj: i0.ɵɵInjectorDeclaration;
~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

Error: node_modules/@angular/fire/compat/analytics/screen-tracking.service.d.ts:11:21 - error TS2694: Namespace '"/home/miguel/PhpstormProjects/pictureDragAndDrop/node_modules/@angular/core/core"' has no exported member 'ɵɵFactoryDeclaration'.

11     static ɵfac: i0.ɵɵFactoryDeclaration<ScreenTrackingService, [null, { optional: true; }, { optional: true; }, null, null, null, { optional: true; }]>;
~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

Error: node_modules/@angular/fire/compat/analytics/screen-tracking.service.d.ts:12:22 - error TS2694: Namespace '"/home/miguel/PhpstormProjects/pictureDragAndDrop/node_modules/@angular/core/core"' has no exported member 'ɵɵInjectableDeclaration'.

12     static ɵprov: i0.ɵɵInjectableDeclaration;
~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

Error: node_modules/@angular/fire/compat/analytics/user-tracking.service.d.ts:10:21 - error TS2694: Namespace '"/home/miguel/PhpstormProjects/pictureDragAndDrop/node_modules/@angular/core/core"' has no exported member 'ɵɵFactoryDeclaration'.

10     static ɵfac: i0.ɵɵFactoryDeclaration<UserTrackingService, never>;
~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

Error: node_modules/@angular/fire/compat/analytics/user-tracking.service.d.ts:11:22 - error TS2694: Namespace '"/home/miguel/PhpstormProjects/pictureDragAndDrop/node_modules/@angular/core/core"' has no exported member 'ɵɵInjectableDeclaration'.

11     static ɵprov: i0.ɵɵInjectableDeclaration;
~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

Error: node_modules/@angular/fire/compat/auth/auth.d.ts:45:21 - error TS2694: Namespace '"/home/miguel/PhpstormProjects/pictureDragAndDrop/node_modules/@angular/core/core"' has no exported member 'ɵɵFactoryDeclaration'.

45     static ɵfac: i0.ɵɵFactoryDeclaration<AngularFireAuth, [null, { optional: true; }, null, null, null, { optional: true; }, { optional: true; }, { optional: true; }, { optional: true; }, { optional: true; }, { optional: true; }]>;
~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

Error: node_modules/@angular/fire/compat/auth/auth.d.ts:46:22 - error TS2694: Namespace '"/home/miguel/PhpstormProjects/pictureDragAndDrop/node_modules/@angular/core/core"' has no exported member 'ɵɵInjectableDeclaration'.

46     static ɵprov: i0.ɵɵInjectableDeclaration;
~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

Error: node_modules/@angular/fire/compat/auth/auth.module.d.ts:4:21 - error TS2694: Namespace '"/home/miguel/PhpstormProjects/pictureDragAndDrop/node_modules/@angular/core/core"' has no exported member 'ɵɵFactoryDeclaration'.

4     static ɵfac: i0.ɵɵFactoryDeclaration<AngularFireAuthModule, never>;
~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

Error: node_modules/@angular/fire/compat/auth/auth.module.d.ts:5:21 - error TS2694: Namespace '"/home/miguel/PhpstormProjects/pictureDragAndDrop/node_modules/@angular/core/core"' has no exported member 'ɵɵNgModuleDeclaration'.

5     static ɵmod: i0.ɵɵNgModuleDeclaration<AngularFireAuthModule, never, never, never>;
~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

[[39m91m
Error: node_modules/@angular/fire/compat/auth/auth.module.d.ts:6:21 - error TS2694: Namespace '"/home/miguel/PhpstormProjects/pictureDragAndDrop/node_modules/@angular/core/core"' has no exported member 'ɵɵInjectorDeclaration'.

6     static ɵinj: i0.ɵɵInjectorDeclaration;
~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

Error: node_modules/@angular/fire/compat/firebase.app.module.d.ts:11:21 - error TS2694: Namespace '"/home/miguel/PhpstormProjects/pictureDragAndDrop/node_modules/@angular/core/core"' has no exported member 'ɵɵFactoryDeclaration'.

11     static ɵfac: i0.ɵɵFactoryDeclaration<AngularFireModule, never>;
~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

Error: node_modules/@angular/fire/compat/firebase.app.module.d.ts:12:21 - error TS2694: Namespace '"/home/miguel/PhpstormProjects/pictureDragAndDrop/node_modules/@angular/core/core"' has no exported member 'ɵɵNgModuleDeclaration'.

12     static ɵmod: i0.ɵɵNgModuleDeclaration<AngularFireModule, never, never, never>;
~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

Error: node_modules/@angular/fire/compat/firebase.app.module.d.ts:13:21 - error TS2694: Namespace '"/home/miguel/PhpstormProjects/pictureDragAndDrop/node_modules/@angular/core/core"' has no exported member 'ɵɵInjectorDeclaration'.

13     static ɵinj: i0.ɵɵInjectorDeclaration;
~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

Error: node_modules/@angular/fire/compat/firestore/firestore.d.ts:127:21 - error TS2694: Namespace '"/home/miguel/PhpstormProjects/pictureDragAndDrop/node_modules/@angular/core/core"' has no exported member 'ɵɵFactoryDeclaration'.

127     static ɵfac: i0.ɵɵFactoryDeclaration<AngularFirestore, [null, { optional: true; }, { optional: true; }, { optional: true; }, null, null, null, { optional: true; }, { optional: true; }, { optional: true; }, { optional: true; }, { optional: true; }, { optional: true; }, { optional: true; }, { optional: true; }, { optional: true; }]>;
~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

Error: node_modules/@angular/fire/compat/firestore/firestore.d.ts:128:22 - error TS2694: Namespace '"/home/miguel/PhpstormProjects/pictureDragAndDrop/node_modules/@angular/core/core"' has no exported member 'ɵɵInjectableDeclaration'.

128     static ɵprov: i0.ɵɵInjectableDeclaration;
~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

Error: node_modules/@angular/fire/compat/firestore/firestore.module.d.ts:10:21 - error TS2694: Namespace '"/home/miguel/PhpstormProjects/pictureDragAndDrop/node_modules/@angular/core/core"' has no exported member 'ɵɵFactoryDeclaration'.

10     static ɵfac: i0.ɵɵFactoryDeclaration<AngularFirestoreModule, never>;
~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

Error: node_modules/@angular/fire/compat/firestore/firestore.module.d.ts:11:21 - error TS2694: Namespace '"/home/miguel/PhpstormProjects/pictureDragAndDrop/node_modules/@angular/core/core"' has no exported member 'ɵɵNgModuleDeclaration'.

11     static ɵmod: i0.ɵɵNgModuleDeclaration<AngularFirestoreModule, never, never, never>;
~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

Error: node_modules/@angular/fire/compat/firestore/firestore.module.d.ts:12:21 - error TS2694: Namespace '"/home/miguel/PhpstormProjects/pictureDragAndDrop/node_modules/@angular/core/core"' has no exported member 'ɵɵInjectorDeclaration'.

12     static ɵinj: i0.ɵɵInjectorDeclaration;
~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

Error: node_modules/@angular/fire/zones.d.ts:19:21 - error TS2694: Namespace '"/home/miguel/PhpstormProjects/pictureDragAndDrop/node_modules/@angular/core/core"' has no exported member 'ɵɵFactoryDeclaration'.

19     static ɵfac: i0.ɵɵFactoryDeclaration<ɵAngularFireSchedulers, never>;
~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

Error: node_modules/@angular/fire/zones.d.ts:20:22 - error TS2694: Namespace '"/home/miguel/PhpstormProjects/pictureDragAndDrop/node_modules/@angular/core/core"' has no exported member 'ɵɵInjectableDeclaration'.

20     static ɵprov: i0.ɵɵInjectableDeclaration<ɵAngularFireSchedulers>;
~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

Error: ./node_modules/@angular/fire/fesm2015/angular-fire-compat.js 124:169-187
"export 'ɵɵFactoryTarget' (imported as 'i0') was not found in '@angular/core'

Error: ./node_modules/@angular/fire/fesm2015/angular-fire-compat-firestore.js 583:773-791
"export 'ɵɵFactoryTarget' (imported as 'i0') was not found in '@angular/core'

Error: ./node_modules/@angular/fire/fesm2015/angular-fire-compat-firestore.js 672:157-175
"export 'ɵɵFactoryTarget' (imported as 'i0') was not found in '@angular/core'

Error: ./node_modules/@angular/fire/fesm2015/angular-fire-compat-analytics.js 141:460-478
"export 'ɵɵFactoryTarget' (imported as 'i0') was not found in '@angular/core'

Error: ./node_modules/@angular/fire/fesm2015/angular-fire-compat-analytics.js 213:261-279
"export 'ɵɵFactoryTarget' (imported as 'i0') was not found in '@angular/core'

Error: ./node_modules/@angular/fire/fesm2015/angular-fire-compat-analytics.js 329:397-415
"export 'ɵɵFactoryTarget' (imported as 'i0') was not found in '@angular/core'

Error: ./node_modules/@angular/fire/fesm2015/angular-fire-compat-analytics.js 352:294-312
"export 'ɵɵFactoryTarget' (imported as 'i0') was not found in '@angular/core'

Error: ./node_modules/@angular/fire/fesm2015/angular-fire.js 140:177-195
"export 'ɵɵFactoryTarget' (imported as 'i0') was not found in '@angular/core'

Error: ./node_modules/@angular/fire/fesm2015/angular-fire-compat-auth.js 125:546-564
"export 'ɵɵFactoryTarget' (imported as 'i0') was not found in '@angular/core'

Error: ./node_modules/@angular/fire/fesm2015/angular-fire-compat-auth.js 181:155-173
"export 'ɵɵFactoryTarget' (imported as 'i0') was not found in '@angular/core'

Error: ./node_modules/@angular/fire/fesm2015/angular-fire-compat.js 127:0-27
"export 'ɵɵngDeclareClassMetadata' (imported as 'i0') was not found in '@angular/core'

Error: ./node_modules/@angular/fire/fesm2015/angular-fire-compat-firestore.js 585:0-27
"export 'ɵɵngDeclareClassMetadata' (imported as 'i0') was not found in '@angular/core'

Error: ./node_modules/@angular/fire/fesm2015/angular-fire-compat-firestore.js 675:0-27
"export 'ɵɵngDeclareClassMetadata' (imported as 'i0') was not found in '@angular/core'

Error: ./node_modules/@angular/fire/fesm2015/angular-fire-compat-analytics.js 143:0-27
"export 'ɵɵngDeclareClassMetadata' (imported as 'i0') was not found in '@angular/core'
[3[39m9m
Error: ./node_modules/@angular/fire/fesm2015/angular-fire-compat-analytics.js 215:0-27
"export 'ɵɵngDeclareClassMetadata' (imported as 'i0') was not found in '@angular/core'

Error: ./node_modules/@angular/fire/fesm2015/angular-fire-compat-analytics.js 331:0-27
"export 'ɵɵngDeclareClassMetadata' (imported as 'i0') was not found in '@angular/core'

Error: ./node_modules/@angular/fire/fesm2015/angular-fire-compat-analytics.js 355:0-27
"export 'ɵɵngDeclareClassMetadata' (imported as 'i0') was not found in '@angular/core'

Error: ./node_modules/@angular/fire/fesm2015/angular-fire.js 142:0-27
"export 'ɵɵngDeclareClassMetadata' (imported as 'i0') was not found in '@angular/core'

Error: ./node_modules/@angular/fire/fesm2015/angular-fire-compat-auth.js 127:0-27
"export 'ɵɵngDeclareClassMetadata' (imported as 'i0') was not found in '@angular/core'

Error: ./node_modules/@angular/fire/fesm2015/angular-fire-compat-auth.js 184:0-27
"export 'ɵɵngDeclareClassMetadata' (imported as 'i0') was not found in '@angular/core'

Error: ./node_modules/@angular/fire/fesm2015/angular-fire-compat.js 124:25-46
"export 'ɵɵngDeclareFactory' (imported as 'i0') was not found in '@angular/core'

Error: ./node_modules/@angular/fire/fesm2015/angular-fire-compat-firestore.js 583:24-45
"export 'ɵɵngDeclareFactory' (imported as 'i0') was not found in '@angular/core'

Error: ./node_modules/@angular/fire/fesm2015/angular-fire-compat-firestore.js 672:30-51
"export 'ɵɵngDeclareFactory' (imported as 'i0') was not found in '@angular/core'

Error: ./node_modules/@angular/fire/fesm2015/angular-fire-compat-analytics.js 141:28-49
"export 'ɵɵngDeclareFactory' (imported as 'i0') was not found in '@angular/core'

Error: ./node_modules/@angular/fire/fesm2015/angular-fire-compat-analytics.js 213:27-48
"export 'ɵɵngDeclareFactory' (imported as 'i0') was not found in '@angular/core'

Error: ./node_modules/@angular/fire/fesm2015/angular-fire-compat-analytics.js 329:29-50
"export 'ɵɵngDeclareFactory' (imported as 'i0') was not found in '@angular/core'

Error: ./node_modules/@angular/fire/fesm2015/angular-fire-compat-analytics.js 352:34-55
"export 'ɵɵngDeclareFactory' (imported as 'i0') was not found in '@angular/core'

Error: ./node_modules/@angular/fire/fesm2015/angular-fire.js 140:30-51
"export 'ɵɵngDeclareFactory' (imported as 'i0') was not found in '@angular/core'

Error: ./node_modules/@angular/fire/fesm2015/angular-fire-compat-auth.js 125:23-44
"export 'ɵɵngDeclareFactory' (imported as 'i0') was not found in '@angular/core'

Error: ./node_modules/@angular/fire/fesm2015/angular-fire-compat-auth.js 181:29-50
"export 'ɵɵngDeclareFactory' (imported as 'i0') was not found in '@angular/core'

Error: ./node_modules/@angular/fire/fesm2015/angular-fire-compat-firestore.js 584:25-49
"export 'ɵɵngDeclareInjectable' (imported as 'i0') was not found in '@angular/core'

Error: ./node_modules/@angular/fire/fesm2015/angular-fire-compat-analytics.js 142:29-53
"export 'ɵɵngDeclareInjectable' (imported as 'i0') was not found in '@angular/core'

Error: ./node_modules/@angular/fire/fesm2015/angular-fire-compat-analytics.js 214:28-52
"export 'ɵɵngDeclareInjectable' (imported as 'i0') was not found in '@angular/core'

Error: ./node_modules/@angular/fire/fesm2015/angular-fire-compat-analytics.js 330:30-54
"export 'ɵɵngDeclareInjectable' (imported as 'i0') was not found in '@angular/core'

Error: ./node_modules/@angular/fire/fesm2015/angular-fire.js 141:31-55
"export 'ɵɵngDeclareInjectable' (imported as 'i0') was not found in '@angular/core'

Error: ./node_modules/@angular/fire/fesm2015/angular-fire-compat-auth.js 126:24-48
"export 'ɵɵngDeclareInjectable' (imported as 'i0') was not found in '@angular/core'

Error: ./node_modules/@angular/fire/fesm2015/angular-fire-compat.js 126:25-47
"export 'ɵɵngDeclareInjector' (imported as 'i0') was not found in '@angular/core'

Error: ./node_modules/@angular/fire/fesm2015/angular-fire-compat-firestore.js 674:30-52
"export 'ɵɵngDeclareInjector' (imported as 'i0') was not found in '@angular/core'

Error: ./node_modules/@angular/fire/fesm2015/angular-fire-compat-analytics.js 354:34-56
"export 'ɵɵngDeclareInjector' (imported as 'i0') was not found in '@angular/core'
[9[39m1m
Error: ./node_modules/@angular/fire/fesm2015/angular-fire-compat-auth.js 183:29-51
"export 'ɵɵngDeclareInjector' (imported as 'i0') was not found in '@angular/core'

Error: ./node_modules/@angular/fire/fesm2015/angular-fire-compat.js 125:25-47
"export 'ɵɵngDeclareNgModule' (imported as 'i0') was not found in '@angular/core'

Error: ./node_modules/@angular/fire/fesm2015/angular-fire-compat-firestore.js 673:30-52
"export 'ɵɵngDeclareNgModule' (imported as 'i0') was not found in '@angular/core'

Error: ./node_modules/@angular/fire/fesm2015/angular-fire-compat-analytics.js 353:34-56
"export 'ɵɵngDeclareNgModule' (imported as 'i0') was not found in '@angular/core'

Error: ./node_modules/@angular/fire/fesm2015/angular-fire-compat-auth.js 182:29-51
"export 'ɵɵngDeclareNgModule' (imported as 'i0') was not found in '@angular/core'

Comment: What Angular version? And did you try deleting node_modules and package.lock and running nom install again?

Comment: yes i did. My angular version is 11

Comment: It looks like a versioning issue.. maybe your firebase version is incorrect?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.